# Where to define Entity ID and Template ID in AWS cognito for SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

Some requirements are mandatory that needs to be set up to send SMS messages to people in India -> Entity ID and Template ID.
We are using cognito and SNS to send messages for SMS verifications. Where do we define those attributes to be compliant. Everything is being done by cognito.

Comment: I am facing this same issue. Unable to send SMS due to this.

Comment: Anyone has the answer please?

Comment: I have this same question